# How to abort window.print();

Tags: jquery

I have a page that uses `window.print();` which is already printed in the source.

But I want for a certain situation via a link trigger, maybe, to nullify/abort this command.
Basically telling the page not to launch print dialog when something is clicked to launch the page.
Maybe with `window.close();`, but no idea where to put, because the page has already printed `window.print();`

Allow me to clarify:
page 'MYPAGE' has `window.print();` printed in the source.

1. Link A opens a new page 'MYPAGE', and launches a Print dialog. Expected.
2. Link B wants to open the same page ('MYPAGE') for different usage, but  do not want the Print dialog.

Is it possible with jQuery?

Comment: Thanks. Please provide answer so I can choose, even if the answer is no :) Thanks

Comment: Pass a URL param if you can. Link A might have on the end of it `?print=1` whereas Link B won't have the `print` arg. Otherwise have the page store a cookie saying it's already tried to print, and then when they click B, it will check the cookie and skip the `print()`.

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but the issue is the window.print(); command is already printed/ hardcoded by some module, and no possible way to alter it via some alter wich is common in drupal. Its all or nothing dead variables 'sendtoprint' which is not passed by reference. Unless I hack it which is a no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a variable into the URL and use `window.location.search.substring(1).indexOf('print') != -1` to see if it has print in the URL and use a condition to block it.

Or instead of blocking it later, if you anticipate that you won't need the `window.print()` command again on that page, you can just do `window.print = function() { }` before your `window.print()` and it won't do anything (based on whether print is in the query string)